# How to install android on blank Phone?

Tags: recovery-mode

So let me consider my phone **blank** after some of messy things I did on it. I flash CWM that is not for my model but for MTK. Well I have the stock ROM downloaded and all I need is to boot to recovery but the problem is It wont boot into. Is there anything that I can do to restore back my recovery. I already know how to flash ROM, I just need the recovery.


Thanks in advance !

Comment: You could try flashing a working recovery to your phone via fastboot, and then working your way to a working rom from there.

Comment: Recovery images are designed for specific models.  Please edit your question with the exact model number of your phone so that we can help you find the correct recovery image.

Answer (score -2):

You could try using a pc and going into Fastboot on the phone and flashing a new recovery.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Perhaps a link to a recovery image with step-by-step installation instructions.